# Insulating data cables through inevitable choke point containing electrical wires

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, network

I unfortunately need to run Cat5E and coax through a choke point containing electrical wires. Would there be a way to add insulation to these wires at these choke points?

[image: picture of choke point]

Details: this picture is from the garage, pointing towards the house's wall. We're adding a single story suite that wraps around the back of the garage. The wires and plumbing is from the basement. The black conduit runs along the back of the garage to the suite's panel at the other end. Not much room to play with.

**Edit #1**

The goal is to insulate and protect from EMI.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you talking about building insulation to stop heat loss? Electrical shielding to protect data lines from interference? More details please. You can use the Edit button to add to your post.

Comment: @JACK - Aren't they just standard NM cables, of different sizes?

Comment: @SteveSh You're probably right. My phone's still recovering from the holidays.

Comment: @MTA to protect from EMI.

Comment: metal conduit grounded on both ends

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to add any kind of electrical insulation here. The low and high voltage cables are made of materials that make supplemental insulation unnecessary in normal situations.

If you want to add insulation anyway, note also that separation is as good as insulation. You can use brackets, mounting clips, etc to affix the low and high voltage cables to the structure so that some amount of separation is maintained (none is technically required here).

Having said all that, you could add "insulation" in the form of a conduit wrapping around the cables. If the cables are long, or they're already terminated, such that the ends can't be freed and passed through a section of conduit, then you could slit the conduit lengthwise. Pry it open, insert the cables through the gap, then slide it along the cable(s) until it is positioned where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

Your edit #1 reveals that you said "insulation" but you meant "EMI shielding." So your concern is that electrical noise on the power lines will interfere with the digital signals.

If you run the digital cables through grounded metal conduit, this will 100% shield them from any interference created by nearby power cables. Each connection between conduit and any boxes or fittings must be wrench tight in order to maintain ground continuity and effective shielding.

Answer (score 1):

The reason data cables need to be separated from the power cables is so you don’t have a single point of failure that could cause power line voltage to be present on a low-voltage device. Use metallic conduit. And while you’re doing that, you might as well install it correctly, including grounding it, which coincidentally rejects all EMI as well.

That said, you don’t *need* to insulate coax for TV, or cat5e for Ethernet, from the magnetic waves emitted from power cables.

1. CATV and Ethernet operate in radio frequencies; AC power – in the US, 60Hz sine waves – is audio frequency, which is easily rejected by the high-pass filter on  even a mediocrely designed RF device.
2. Both coaxial cable and cat5e are physically designed to reject noise. Coax passes the signal on the inner conductor; the outer conductor is grounded. Cat5e uses differential signals on twisted pairs of conductors. Any interference will affect both conductors equally, in opposite directions, which does not change the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit indicates this is to prevent EMI.

Generally you don't need to worry about interference between typical low voltage wiring and line voltage, for the following reasons:

- Low voltage systems are designed to work fine with 60Hz induced in the wiring
- Low voltage systems typically use twisted pair wiring which rejects EMI
- Anything that runs on 60Hz AC assumes that there will be other noise on the line and filters it out if necessary
- Your coupling distance isn't very long

There's a couple of very narrow exceptions such as if you are planning for these low voltage cables to be used for HAM radio signals or low level unbalanced audio signals. If you don't have any of those situations in play, you're good to go, no need to add extra shielding. In fact, if done poorly extra shielding can even induce more noise or cause filtering of the signal due to extra capacitance.

For the proposed wiring (Cat5e) and the assumed use of Ethernet, there's zero reason to shield it from the AC. The frequencies used for Ethernet are also high enough to be well out of the way of most Ham bands.